# React 16 setState method clarification

Tags: reactjs

I was reading the react 16 features. I stuck on the below point. can anyone please clarify the below point.

> setState callbacks (second argument) now fire immediately after
>   componentDidMount / componentDidUpdate instead of after all components
>   have rendered.

What will be the difference when below code executes in both version of react i.e < 16 and 16.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: 'default'}
  }

  changeState() {
    this.setState({name: 'shubham'}, ()=> this.callbackSuccess())
  }

  callbackSuccess() {
    console.log('call back success');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <Child1 name={`fromchild 1 ${this.state.name}`}/>
        <Child2 name={`fromchild 2 ${this.state.name}`}/>
        <Child3 name={`fromchild 3 ${this.state.name}`}/>
        <p className="App-intro" onClick={() => this.changeState()}>
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log('component did update prevprops',prevProps)
    console.log('component did update prevState',prevState)
  }

  componentDidMount(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log('component did mount')
  }

}

class Child1 extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('child1 render')
    const {name} = this.props;
    return (<h1> from child1 {name}</h1>)
  }
}

class Child2 extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('child2 render')
    const {name} = this.props;
    return (<h1> from child2 {name}</h1>)
  }
}

class Child3 extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('child3 render')
    const {name} = this.props;
    return (<h1> from child3 {name}</h1>)
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: In this specific example i don't see any difference. The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) also mentions one more thing about the callback: "_The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered. Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic instead._"

Answer (score 1):

From React 16, the parent component mount is not dependent on the child components mount.

Before React 16, `componentDidMount` (respec. `componentDidUpdate`) would fire for a parent component only after all child components have fired their `componentDidMount` (respec. `componentDidUpdate`) .

Also, remember, the setState callback ( 2nd argument ) is executed after re-rending which a responsibility of the lifecycle method `componentDidUpdate`.

If this is clear, `componentDidUpdate` ( or the callback of setState) are independent between parent component and its children. That's why:

> setState callbacks (second argument) now fire immediately after
>   componentDidMount / componentDidUpdate instead of after all components
>   have rendered.

"after all components have rendered" ,means : after all child components have rendered.

### Apply that for your example :

Your example is useless to demonstrate the difference between ( >React 16 )  and (< React 16) in the related point . Indeed, child components are stateless even you are implementing it using class not function. In other words, child components of your example does not include neither `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate` nor `setState` with 2nd arg callback.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can you please give me the example of that? If you have time.